# gorm primary key dont appear in database

Tags: database, go, model

im a beginner in golang. when im using `gorm:"primaryKey"` [image]

i dont see any field that use primary key

this is my model

```
type Orders struct {
    OrderID      uint64    `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"orderId"`
    CustomerName string    `json:"customerName"`
    OrderedAt    time.Time `json:"orderedAt" example:"2020-01-09T21:21:46+00:00"`
    Items        []Items   `json:"items"`
}

type Items struct {
    ItemID      uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"lineItemId"`
    Item_code   string `json:"itemCode"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
    Quantity    int    `json:"quantity"`
}
```

which part do i wrong?
and do i need relational database for items field?

Comment: Were the DB tables, that show no primary key,  created from `Orders` and `Items` struct using gorm? i.e. `AutoMigrate`?

Comment: `db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "root:@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/orders_by?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local")
 
if err != nil {
  panic("failed to connect database")
 }
 
db.AutoMigrate(&models.Orders{}, &models.Items{})
 
return db`

Answer (score 0):

Lets be clear over here,
At first you need to declare a struct as a Model i.e by

```
type Anything struct {
    gorm.Model
    ... (other fields)
}
```

And then in order to use Has Many relation you need to use the ID of the parent on the child i.e

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  CreditCards []CreditCard
}

type CreditCard struct {
  gorm.Model
  Number string
  UserID uint    (like this over here.)
}
```

Please do kindly follow the docs [GORM Docs](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html)

Comment: It is not mandatory to embed `gorm.Model`, if there is existing primary key than that can be used for referencing

Answer (score 0):

In the model Orders model has a hasMany relation to Items, but Items is missing the Key of Orders.

The `db.AutoMigrate(&models.Orders{}, &models.Items{})` should be failing to create in this case for `Order.Items`, but the error is ignored.

Include OrdersID in Items struct to complete referential integrity because gorm expects default primary key/ foreign key as `<StructName>ID` so for `Orders` it will search `OrdersID` in `Items`

```
type Orders struct {
  OrdersID      uint64    `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"orderId"`
  ...
}

type Items struct {
  OrdersID uint64
  ...
}
```

Suggestion, structs should be called `Order` and `Item` rather than `Orders` and `Items` thus the model becomes

```
type Order struct {
    OrderID      uint64    `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"orderId"`
    CustomerName string    `json:"customerName"`
    OrderedAt    time.Time `json:"orderedAt" example:"2020-01-09T21:21:46+00:00"`
    Items        []Item    `json:"items"`
}

type Item struct {
    ItemID      uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"lineItemId"`
    Item_code   string `json:"itemCode"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
    Quantity    int    `json:"quantity"`
    OrderID     uint64
}
```